# Prevent asp.net system from killing a thread

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, process, bulk-email

I'm sending bulk mail from an asp.net application but after sending 80 emails the thread is killed by the system. Anyone knows a way to keep the thread alive until it finishes? I saw that there are ways to multi-threading and background processing but I need a quick working solution. Something to tell the system to mind its own business until I have the time to re-do the sending function.

I tried to change the tag `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300"/>` in web.config but doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have a queue system available to you? Threads are lightweight devices, sending emails sounds like a heavyweight thing you'd have a whole process for.

Comment: Heavyness is not the problem, time is. I need to send up to 2000 emails at a time, so it tooks a while and after 70-80 emails the thread is killed because the system thinks that the process is hanging

Comment: Doesn't that support my view that you should not be using a thread for this? I don't use Windows, but it still sounds more appropriate for a separate process. I wonder whether you might be blacklisted for sending mail that quickly anyway - the paradox of scaling SMTP sending is that is needs to be done more slowly, not more quickly.